# How to improve an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, worker, sidekiq

I have a method which returns the results from a query.  The code that calls the method then loops through each result and launches a sidekiq worker.  The problem I'm running into is that the looping is actually taking a decent amount of time (almost the same amount of time it takes to run all the workers).  Here's the query:

```
Object.where("last_updated > ?" , 1.days.ago.midnight )
```

I then do the following:

```
objects.each { |o| o.perform_async(something) }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make this process more efficient.  The result is that it's taking around 10 minutes for this process to complete, effectively taking 20 milliseconds per launch (if the query returns 30,000 results).  Is there any way to make this quicker?

Comment: last_updated is obviously indexed right?  And the index is a btree one? .. (not a hash index).   Also, if you are expecting 30k results.. use AR find_in_batches()

Comment: @ilanberci quick question though ... can I return find_in_batches and return that from a method and it operate the same way?  Also, yes, last_updated is indexed as a btree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you already have last_updated indexed. Next:

```
Object.select('id, only_columns_you_need').where(...).find_each do |object|
  object.perform_async(something)
end
```

If the "objects" table has lots of columns but you only need a few for this operation, selecting *only those columns* can really speed things up in both db and Ruby land.

`find_each` will load the records in batches of 1000 by default. Use the `:batch_size` option to tweak that.

**UPDATE**

```
def do_stuff_to_objects(&stuff)
  Object.select('id, only_columns_you_need').where(...).find_each(&stuff)
end

...

do_stuff_to_objects do |object|
  object.perform_async(something)
end
```

Comment: Can I return find_each from a function though?  That's the main issue I'm running into  here

Comment: No, but you could pass control through with a block, which could give you a similar result. See edit above.

Comment: Fair point ... I'll have to think about my implementation but thanks for your answer!